# "Dein" ist mein ganzes Herz

Tags: possessive

Ich wollte fragen wie solche Formulierungen heißen: "Dein ist mein ganzes Herz," "Denn dein ist das Reich und die Kraft ..."

Ich verstehe die Sätze (Dein Herz, dein Reich statt dem ganzen Teil), trotzdem hören sie sich irgendwie überholt oder formell an. Könnte jemand hier mich auf ein grammatikalisches Phänomen bzgl. "dein" hier hinweisen?

Comment: Scheint u.a. biblischer Sprachgebrauch zu sein. "Die Rache ist mein" etc.

Answer (score 3):

*Dein* ist ein Possessivpronomen, das die Zugehörigkeit eines Dings zu einer Person bestimmt, die in der zweiten Person angesprochen wird.

Normalerweise (in gängiger Alltagssprache) wird *dein* zusammen mit einem weiteren Substantiv verwendet, das die Zugehörigkeit näher beschreibt:

> Mein Herz ist dein Eigentum

In gehobener/veralteter Sprache kann das beschreibende Substantiv weggelassen werden (es trägt sowieso wie im obigen Beispiel nicht besonders viel Information, die nicht in *dein* schon vorhanden wäre) und *dein* fast wie ein Adjektiv verwendet werden:

> Mein Herz ist dein

und natürlich darf im Deutschen die Satzstellung auch so verändert werden, dass das Pronomen an den Anfang des Satzes rutscht (was sich möglicherweise noch etwas "getragener" anhört) zu:

> Dein ist mein Herz

> Dein ist das Reich und die Kraft...

Der [Online-Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dein_Possessivpronomen) verliert ein paar Worte über diesen "gehobenen" Gebrauch ohne Substantiv.

Comment: Oder analog zu *mi casa es tu casa*: *Mein Herz ist dein Herz*; *das Reich ist dein Reich*.

Comment: Bei Auslassung müßte es aber *deins* heißen: *Mein Handy ist besser als deins/\*dein*.

Comment: @DavidVogt Warum?

Answer (score 0):

Die Ausdrücke "... ist mein", "... ist dein", "... ist euer", "... ist unser" sind aus der Mode gekommen und fast überall durch "gehört mir/dir/euch/uns" ersetzt worden, was dasselbe bedeutet.

> Der Sieg ist unser! (Der Sieg gehört uns!)
> Gegen zwölf Gulden sind die Teppiche Euer. (Für zwölf Gulden gehören die Teppiche euch.)
> Lass von ihm ab, Luise -- Adalbert ist mein! (Adalbert gehört mir!) 
> Dein ist mein ganzes Herz! (Dir gehört mein ganzes Herz!)

Comment: Der attributive Gebrauch ist schon noch sehr gebräuchlich. "Das ist *unser Sieg*!" – "... sind das *eure Teppiche*." – "Das ist *mein Adalbert*!" – "Mein ganzes Herz ist *dein ganzes Herz*!" – und ganz oft bei Kindern: "Das ist *mein Spielzeug*!"

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Klar. Vom "attributiven Gebrauch", sprich den normalen Possessivpronomen, war hier allerdings nicht die Rede. Ich vermute nicht, dass der/die OP dazu irgendwelche Fragen hat.